# GUI framework error after Update

Tags: pdftex, miktex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix the error "GUI framework cannot be initialized" with TeXnicCenter and MiKTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27138/how-can-i-fix-the-error-gui-framework-cannot-be-initialized-with-texniccenter-a)

Yesterday I updated all packages via the Miktex 2.8 update funktion. Since then, when I use `\usepackage{geometry}` oder `\usepackage{hyperref}`, the compiling process stops with error message

> pdflatex.exe: GUI framework cannot be
>   initialized

and produces no output at all. All my other packages and stuff works just fine. Aditionally the temporary file

> main.synctex(busy)

doesn't disappear. I know about the activate On the Fly solution, it doesn't work. Neither does un- and reinstalling those packages via package manager. Unfortunately I have no admin-rights on this computer, otherwise I would just reinstall Miktex completely.

Comment: Which editor do you use?

Comment: My bet: texniccenter. http://www.miktex.org/2.8/issues

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate of a newer question which is a bit more descriptive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first: You don't need admin rights to install and use miktex. You can install and run it in a restricted account in single user mode.

At second: The problem is probably that hyperref and geometry (or a package they load) try to load a third package which is not installed. Compile once on the command line to find out which package is missing.