# TeXnicCenter won't build when using pgf package

Tags: packages, pgf-core

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I fix the error “GUI framework cannot be initialized” with TeXnicCenter and MiKTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27138/how-can-i-fix-the-error-gui-framework-cannot-be-initialized-with-texniccenter)

I recently installed the "pgf" package via the MiKTeX package installer. I attempted to use the pgf file in a TeX file using TeXnicCenter. However, when I included the line "usepackage{pgf}" and attempted to build the output I would always get the following message at the end of the output profile:

> LaTeX-Result: 0 Error(s), 1 Warning(s), 0 Bad Box(es), 0 Page(s)

However, according to the output profile multiple files from the pgf package were loaded, so it's definitely been installed. When I remove the line "usepackage{pgf}" from the TeX file the file built and displayed perfectly (I had not included any pgf code in the file). In the output profile, after four pgf-related files are listed, is the line:

> latex.exe: GUI framework cannot be initialized.

This is the last line in the output profile before BibTeX takes over. I suspect it points to the issue. Is this the case, and if so how do I fix it?

Comment: Does [How can I fix the error “GUI framework cannot be initialized” with TeXnicCenter and MiKTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27138/5764) solve your problem?

Comment: @Werner It might, thank you very much for the link. I'm currently updating MiKTeX to see if that fixes the problem and will report back once I'm finished (my internet connection is slow). If it does, feel free to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: @Werner That fixed the problem. Thanks so much.