# Commands from graphics have no effect

Tags: graphics, scaling

I am learning LaTeX from a book, and I am using TeXnicCenter. The book has a chapter about the `graphics` package, so I download it and try the commands. But I find that when I use commands like `\scalebox` and `\resizebox`, they cannot take effect. Also, the PDF seems to be "dead" after that, i.e. when I make some changes and click "build and view", the PDF remains unchanged. I have tried the `graphicx` package but the result is the same.

For example, firstly I type

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amstext, amssymb, amscd, ulem, array}
\begin{document}
abc
\end{document}
```

then this produces a pdf with a word 'abc'. At the bottom of TeXnicCenter, I see
0 error, 0 warning, 0 bad box, and 1 page.

Then I change it to

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amstext, amssymb, amscd, ulem, array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\scalebox{2}{abc}
\end{document}
```

The same pdf occurs, i.e. no size enlarged. At the bottom of TeXnicCenter, I see
0 error, 0 warning, 0 bad box, and 0 page.

Finally I change it to

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amstext, amssymb, amscd, ulem, array}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\scalebox{2}{efg}
\end{document}
```

I still see the word 'abc' with the same size. At the bottom of TeXnicCenter, I see
0 error, 0 warning, 0 bad box, and 0 page.

Would any one please help me?

In the output area of the TeXnicCenter, I find the following which is unusual:

"C\User\user\Desktop\myfile\test.aux)pdflatex.exe: GUI framework cannot be initialized."

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: If you want to use `scalebox` you need to add `\usepackage{graphics}`in your preamble. Add a compilable code !

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your input: should work fine. So the conclusion is something else is up. Is it possible for you to make the `.log` file available somewhere so we can see what problems are happening?

Comment: Where can I find such .log file?

Comment: @ericc The .log file should be located in the same folder as your .tex file.

Comment: I can't find the .log file. My file name is "test", and I just find test.aux, test.bbl, test.blg, test.dvi, test.txt, test.pdf, test.ps, test.tex. On the other hand, I have found some error message and have edited the questions.

Comment: As for the error, this is a common issue, apparently only seen with TexnicCenter. Try running `pdflatex` on this file from a command line (dos prompt) instead. Then MikTeX will ask for permission to install something. That interface cannot be launched from within TC.

Comment: I just solve the issue by using command prompt and changing some setting. These also appear in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27138/how-can-i-fix-the-error-gui-framework-cannot-be-initialized-with-texniccenter. Thanks the commands above for locating the problem.